How can I create a Media object in javafx from a byte array?
I am trying to play media in javafx using MediaView, MediaPlayer, and Media.  The Media class seems to only accept a URL source to create Media (which is used to pass to the MediaPlayer).  I would like to pass a cached byte array to create the Media object.  Is this supported?
I was able to play media using a URL and a file, but not a byte array.

For most people, I think there isn't a requirement to have media in memory, as the JavaFX media system is based on gstreamer, which is designed to stream media from secondary storage efficiently.
From the media doc “Only HTTP, HTTPS, FILE, and JAR URIs are supported.”. So you need to serve your bytes from a provider on one of those protocols.
You could run an embedded HTTP server and serve the bytes from that using the HTTP protocol.
Or you could use an in-memory file system, serving the bytes using the file or jar protocols..
Example embedded http server serving content from bytes in memory.
The example serves image mime types, but serving other content types for media would work as long as the input stream is correct (e.g. represents correctly encoded mp3 or mp4 data).

Just wondering, what would a solution using an in-memory file system look like?

From Slaw's comment on testing an in-memory fileysystem approach, it is not compatible with the JavaFX 21 media system.
It would probably be tricky to implement from scratch.
Likely, you need to implement a FileSystem and a FileSystemProvider.
Rather than doing that yourself, you could use an existing implementation such as jimfs.
It may be necessary to reference your custom file system indirectly using the jar protocol rather than the default file protocol. For example, using jar:jimfs://, wrapping the custom file system in a zip to allow a jar protocol.  It would be necessary to create a proof of concept to prove it could be done.
Alternative: Fork JavaFX code
You could fork some of the media code from JavaFX and modify the fork to allow other protocols or constructors that support your in-memory object.
Easy workaround
It is easier though just to write the media bytes to a temp file and access that using the file: protocol instead, as suggested in Slaw's answer.
Consider AudioClip if latency is a concern
@Slaw agreed, based on your analysis, that the in-memory file approach probably isn't going to work.

AudioClip stores in memory the raw, uncompressed audio data for the entire sound, which can be quite large for long audio clips. A MediaPlayer will only have enough decompressed audio data pre-rolled in memory to play for a short amount of time so it is much more memory efficient for long clips, especially if they are compressed.


Thanks for the interesting input.  I will give the in-memory filesystem a try.

Just wondering, what would a solution using an in-memory file system look like?

@Slaw added some hints on how an in-memory file system may be used to the answer.

I hadn't considered trying to "hide" the non-file protocol behind a jar protocol. Unfortunately, when I tried this in JavaFX 22.0.2 an UnsupportedOperationException was still thrown by Media. It seems the implementation specifically checks the secondary protocol for jar URLs. Also, it appears that the JarURLConnection implementation will copy the jar file to a temporary file if the secondary protocol is not file. At least in Java 22.0.2 So, regardless of JavaFX throwing an error, this is unfortunately not a viable approach if the the media's bytes must be kept in memory.

Short of forking JavaFX, I think the OP really only has two choices: (1) Write the media to a temporary file and use a file URI, or (2) run an embedded HTTP server and use an http URI. Which is the better option for OP depends on how important it is that the media remains in memory (assuming JavaFX itself never caches the media to a file; I don't know the implementation well enough to know that for sure).

@Slaw edited the answer to reflect your findings.

Simple Solution - Temp File
The simplest solution would be to write the bytes to a file, then pass a file URI to the Media constructor.
public Media toMediaFile(byte[] bytes, String extension) throws IOException {
  Objects.requireNonNull(bytes);
  if (extension.isBlank())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("blank extension");
  var file = Files.createTempFile("jfxmedia", "." + extension);
  Files.write(file, bytes, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
  return new Media(file.toUri().toString());
}

Note you may want to add code to delete the temporary file when its no longer needed, or even simply when the JVM exits.

Embedded HTTP Server
However, if you want to keep the media's bytes in memory, then I think the easiest (only?) solution would be one of the suggestions in jewelsea's answer: Create an embedded server to serve the media over HTTP. You can use the jdk.httpserver module for this. An example using that module is given in this other jewelsea answer (linked to in their answer to this question). But here is another example that is more specific to your use case.
Server Code
Note this example server is not implemented to handle the Range HTTP header. I believe the JavaFX media implementation will use that header, at least in some cases. You may want to implement the functionality in the server.
Also, it may be easier to find a more feature-rich HTTP server library and add to your project as a dependency, rather than using the jdk.httpserver module. Though the latter should be sufficient for a simple, bare-bones server that only exists to serve byte[] arrays over HTTP on the local host.
InMemoryMedia.java
package com.example;

public record InMemoryMedia(byte[] bytes, String contentType) {
   
  public int contentLength() {
    return bytes.length;
  }
}

InMemoryMediaServer.java
package com.example;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpContext;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class InMemoryMediaServer implements AutoCloseable {

  private final HttpServer httpServer;

  public InMemoryMediaServer(int port) throws IOException {
    var address = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), port);
    httpServer = HttpServer.create(address, 1);
    httpServer.setExecutor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
    httpServer.start();
  }

  public RegistrationKey registerMedia(String path, InMemoryMedia media) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(path);
    Objects.requireNonNull(media);

    var context = httpServer.createContext(path, new InMemoryMediaHandler(media));
    return new RegistrationKey(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    httpServer.stop(0);
  }

  public class RegistrationKey {

    private final AtomicBoolean unregistered = new AtomicBoolean();
    private final HttpContext context;

    RegistrationKey(HttpContext context) {
      this.context = context;
    }

    public URI uri() {
      var addr = httpServer.getAddress();

      var scheme = "http";
      var host = addr.getAddress().getHostAddress();
      int port = addr.getPort();
      var path = path();

      try {
        return new URI(scheme, null, host, port, path, null, null);
      } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
      }
    }

    public String path() {
      return context.getPath();
    }

    public void unregister() {
      if (unregistered.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        httpServer.removeContext(context);
      }
    }
  }
}

InMemoryMediaHandler.java
package com.example;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import java.io.IOException;

final class InMemoryMediaHandler implements HttpHandler {

  private final InMemoryMedia media;

  InMemoryMediaHandler(InMemoryMedia media) {
    this.media = media;
  }

  @Override
  public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
    switch (exchange.getRequestMethod()) {
      case "HEAD" -> {
        setResponseHeaders(exchange.getResponseHeaders());
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, -1);
      }
      case "GET" -> {
        setResponseHeaders(exchange.getResponseHeaders());
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, media.contentLength());
        try (var out = exchange.getResponseBody()) {
          out.write(media.bytes());
        }
      }
      default -> exchange.sendResponseHeaders(405, -1);
    }
  }

  private void setResponseHeaders(Headers headers) {
    headers.set("Accept-Ranges", "none");
    headers.set("Content-Type", media.contentType());
    headers.set("Content-Length", Integer.toString(media.contentLength()));
  }
}

Application Code
Some code showing how to use the InMemoryMediaServer class.
Main.java
package com.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  private InMemoryMediaServer server;
  private String mediaUri;

  @Override
  public void init() throws Exception {
    server = new InMemoryMediaServer(8888);

    var key = server.registerMedia("/test", getInMemoryMedia());
    mediaUri = key.uri().toString();
  }

  private InMemoryMedia getInMemoryMedia() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented"); // TODO: Implement
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var media = new Media(mediaUri);
    media.setOnError(() -> media.getError().printStackTrace());

    var player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.setAutoPlay(true);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(new MediaView(player))));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    server.close();
  }
}

